# Terraform can not refer to resource by index

Tags: terraform

I have an aws instance defied like so

```
resource "aws_instance" "an_instance" {
  count                       = "${var.instance_count}"
......
}
```

which works just fine, BUT when I add this snippet

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "on_host_1_1" {
  availability_zone = "${aws_instance.an_instance[1].availability_zone}"
  snapshot_id       = "snap-abcdca8ee59112345f"
  tags              = "${local.all_tags}"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error reading config for aws_ebs_volume[on_host_1_1]: parse error at 1:31: expected "}" but found "."
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

```
Terraform v0.11.14
+ provider.aws v2.25.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the proper syntax for referencing a specific element of a list. You can see the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/resources.html#using-variables-with-count). Specifically note the section mentioning:

> To reference a particular instance of a resource you can use `resource.foo.*.id[#]` where `#` is the index number of the instance.

Therefore, your resource with the proper syntax would be:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "on_host_1_1" {
  availability_zone = "${aws_instance.an_instance.*.availability_zone[1]}"
  snapshot_id       = "snap-abcdca8ee59112345f"
  tags              = "${local.all_tags}"
}
```

which will give you the behavior you desire. The reason this works is because the splat operator `*` properly signifies to Terraform that the resource output is a list, and not a single element type.

Comment: I think worth noting that the syntax shown in the original question _is_ valid (and preferred) for Terraform 0.12 and later, but not for Terraform 0.11.